# Building chromium android as library [android aar archive]

Tags: android, chromium, android-chrome

Want to build chrome project as aar instead of apk.

Tried to change target_type to android_library from android_apk for chrome public apk but doesn't work.  Looks like it would need a series of changes in different files for eg rules.gni,  internal_rules.gni etc.

If someone has done similar task amd can share the info would be great help

Comment: Did you find a solution?